# Play 2.6 evolutions DB change not applied

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.6, playframework-evolutions

My project was recently updated from Play 2.5 to 2.6.13.
I added a new script 16.sql but the change were not applied in the table **play_evolutions**

According to the [documentation 2.6](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Evolutions), the `EvolutionsComponents` have to be injected if you use compile time DI. But Guice is runtime DI, so I should not have to inject any components.

I enabled the evolutions in the `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(evolutions, jdbc)
```

In application.conf

```
play.evolutions.enabled=true
play.evolutions.autoApply=true
```

What is my project missing ? Any git examples are welcome

Comment: Did you check the evolution script format? First line comment plus a blank line seems mandatory before starting with ups and downs.

Comment: first line is a comment like  "# -- Up"

Comment: I followed the same format evolution script https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Evolutions . The table **play_evolutions** didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by following [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Evolutions) since upgrading to Play 2.6

Here is my code

```
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
import play.api.{Application, ApplicationLoader, BuiltInComponentsFromContext}
import play.api.db.{DBComponents, HikariCPComponents}
import play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsComponents
import play.api.routing.Router
import play.filters.HttpFiltersComponents
import router.Routes

class MyApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {

  def load(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): Application = {
    new AppComponents(context).application
  }
}

class AppComponents(context: Context)
    extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
    with DBComponents
    with EvolutionsComponents
    with HikariCPComponents
    with HttpFiltersComponents {
  // this will actually run the database migrations on startup
  applicationEvolutions

  //  val prefix: String = "/"
  lazy val router = Router.empty
  //  lazy val router: Router = bind(classOf[Routes]).to(classOf[Routes])

}
```

And in the conf/application.conf, add this line

```
play.application.loader=MyApplicationLoader
```